# SVG files not working in P3D (Processing)

Tags: svg, processing

I'm using P3D to create a 3D sketch and I'm trying to lay some GUI on top of it that is composed of .svg images.

```
PShape s;

setup() {
    size(600, 600, P3D);
    s = loadShape("foo.svg"); //place any svg file here
}

draw() {
    background(0);
    shape(s, 0, 0, 100, 100);
}
```

Basically what happens is "foo.svg" will display, but there's a bunch of random errors in the image (weird lines, parts misplaced, etc). It's not an issue with the 3D model underneath, it's simply that P3D doesn't let you display .svg images correctly. Does anyone know of a work-around?

PS (I tried using geomerative, but still ran into the exact same issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could isolate your two coordinate spaces(3D then '2D' on top) using [pushMatrix();](http://processing.org/reference/pushMatrix_.html) and popMatrix();

Here's a modified version of the LoadDisplaySVG sample:

```
PShape bot;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360,P3D);
  bot = loadShape("bot1.svg");
} 

void draw(){
  background(102);
  pushMatrix();//3D
    translate(width * .5,height *.5,-150);
    rotateX(map(mouseX,0,width,-PI,PI));
    rotateY(map(mouseY,0,height,PI,-PI));
    box(150);
  popMatrix();
  pushMatrix();//2D
    shape(bot, 110, 90, 100, 100);  // Draw at coordinate (110, 90) at size 100 x 100
    shape(bot, 280, 40);            // Draw at coordinate (280, 40) at the default size
  popMatrix();
}
```

I've indented the calls to make it easier to spot how the coordinate systems are isolated.
Behind the scenes the nitty gritty matrix multiplication part is done for you.
Simply think of push/pop matrix calls as creating a hierarchy/tree like structure like you get in a 3D editor
to organize your 3D scene.

**UPDATE**

Based on the comment, after having a closer look, P3D doesn't render shapes as nicely as the 2D renderer.

[image: svg 3d]

Another option is to use [PGraphics](http://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html) as a 2D buffer to render into and then display it as an image in your 3D scene:

```
PShape bot;
PImage botimg;
void setup() {
  size(640, 360,P3D);
  bot = loadShape("bot1.svg");
  //2D buffer -> pixels
  PGraphics p = createGraphics(width,height);
  p.beginDraw();
  p.background(0,0);//transparent bg
  p.shape(bot,0,0,bot.width,bot.height);
  p.endDraw();
  //botimg = p;//PGraphics extends PImage so this works or use p.get() to get only pixels cloned 
  botimg = p.get(0,0,ceil(bot.width)+1,ceil(bot.height)+1);//a few extra pixels so we don't clip the image
} 

void draw(){
  if(botimg == null){

  }
  background(102);
  pushMatrix();//3D
    translate(width * .5,height *.5,-150);
    rotateX(map(mouseX,0,width,-PI,PI));
    rotateY(map(mouseY,0,height,PI,-PI));
    box(150);
  popMatrix();
  pushMatrix();//2D
    //shape(bot, 110, 90, 100, 100);  // Draw at coordinate (110, 90) at size 100 x 100
    //shape(bot, 280, 40);            // Draw at coordinate (280, 40) at the default size
    image(botimg,280,40,botimg.width,botimg.height);
  popMatrix();
}
```

Behind the scenes the P3D renderer with generate a quad and texture it when you call image.
You get a better result using a pixels representation of your svg, but it also becomes no longer scalable:

[image: svg3d2d]

Also notice a minor glitch of the 3d stroke on the cube being affected by the texture's transparency.

Comment: Have you tried running this in processing? To me (and I believe we are using the same "bot1.svg" file found on the processing page) the image is slightly distorted -  borders don't match up smoothly and many elements of the image are displaced. Try loading "bot1.svg" using the default renderer and comparing it to the "bot1.svg" loaded in your sketch, the dissimilarities are pretty apparent.